# Permission 'firebasemessagingcampaigns.campaigns.create' denied on resource

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a push message through the Firebase Cloud Messaging Console interface. I don't have the owner permission for my user, I only have the "Firebase Cloud Messaging API Administrator" and "Firebase Cloud Messaging Administrator" permissions in IAM.

When trying to send the notification, an error message appears: Permission 'firebasemessagingcampaigns.campaigns.create' denied on resource 'projects/XXXXXXX'. But I didn't find this permission, the most similar would be "firebaseinappmessaging.campaigns.create". **Could it be a firebase platform bug?**

Error: "There was an error saving the campaign: Permission 'firebasemessagingcampaigns.campaigns.create' denied on resource 'projects/XXXXXXXX' (or resource may not exist)."

Answer (score 1):

I think that we have the same problem. We were trying to make a duplicate of a Push notification campaign. The error in the Web interface of Firebase was: "There was an error retrieving the campaign". (The Owner role worked.)
We solved the problem by adding a new standard role to the user:

- Firebase Grow Admin